# How to get rid of the Print dialog box when opening a file online?

Tags: windows-xp

Everytime I open a file online, it automatically bring up the Print dialog box which makes it unable to read the file. And there is no way to get rid of the Print dialog box. It's Windows XP. I haven't had this problme before untill two days ago. Please help me! Is there some way I can disable such automatic Print dialog box?

Comment: Please give us a little bit more information to work with/ What Browser, What kind of document, what website, what did you change/install/update 2 days ago?